I am not able to launch ros2. the terminal is showing error package not found
ros2 launch br3b_gz_bringup sil.launch.py world:=Raceway_1

I am writing this command to open up gazebo simulator but the terminal is showing that the package is not found. the package is already available in a file. it is searching everything but not able to identify the specified package.

Package 'br3b_gz_bringup' not found:

I have tried to change the path directory.
